# Upgrading SQL2008R2 Developer Edition to SQL2008 R2 Standard/Enterprise

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

Just need to upgrade the version from Developer to Standard.  Is it as simple as just entering in an Enterprise Key or do I need to re-install the SQL Instance ?

Comment: How -- is this a side-by-side install, or overwrite the existing Developer install?  What about the database(s)?

Comment: no side-by-side.  Just need to up the version from Developer to an Enterprise version. It currently has a fresh install of Sharepoint connected to it.

Answer (score 1):

You will need to run the install to perform an upgrade, it's pretty simple however.

**Edit** since I apparently can't read and thought you were using express, there will be almost 0 feature changes made yet I'm pretty sure you still have to re-run the setup program to get the key in and allow it to make the necessary modifications.

Comment: Ok. Considering this envirnoment is connected to a Sharepoint envirnoment, what impacts will it have on it if I re-run the Installation again ?

Comment: Shouldn't have any effects, it only improves it (and the core features aren't really changing).

Comment: What do you mean by "improves"?

Comment: @John Sansom it is just adding some things, like removing the max database size, allowed CPUs, etc...

Comment: Are you sure about that? The Developer edition has more features than are available in the Standard Edition.

Comment: oh wow, I misread that as express (le sigh). editing

Answer (score 0):

you can upgrade by just using a simple tool "Randolph" easy to use and it takes full responsibility for upgrade.It shifts the responsibility for versioning from the users to the software. Its light-weight, easy to use tool that runs in the background and keeps track of all your databases schema and data changes over time, and enables full review of databases' history, and full rollback to any point in time, as well as optionally push changes into existing systems.
Also refer:  http://www.nobhillsoft.com/Randolph.aspx